# Rails country select dropdown for search: how to show priority countries at the top

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to perform a custom search and want to pass the country as one of the options to perform the search. My controller action for the search looks like this:

```
@articles = Article.filter(params.slice(:category, :country, :src_url, :date, :lang, :keywords, :title))
.where(is_active: true)
.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

And my model contains all these scopes (example: scope :country, -> (country) { where country: country }

So I've tried a few options, and so far didn't find one that I would be satisfied with completely.

**Option 1:**

```
<%= select_tag :country, options_from_collection_for_select(ISO3166::Country.countries.sort_by(&:name), 'name', 'name', params[:country]), :include_blank => true %>
```

*Pros:* Almost what I want - clean and short.

*Cons:* Can't figure out how is it working, really. I found it somewhere and modified a little using trial and error. But I didn't manage to find any documentation that would point on why and how it works, and with trial and error I can only go as far. From this comes the issue - I can't modify it to show particular countries on top of the list and rest sorted below.

**Option 2:**

```
<%= country_select(nil, :country, { priority_countries: %w(RU BR IN CN ZA), include_blank: true, selected: params[:country] }, {}) %>
```

*Pros:* It does exactly what I want with 1 exception.

*Cons:* It requires something called "user" as first argument, which I have set to as nil, and it leads to weird behavior in GET - it passes '%5Bcountry%5D=' instead of simply 'country=' and I don't like it. I didn't find a way to get rid of it or work around it.

Any suggestions of how to do it better / cleaner?

Comment: who said you need to pass `user` to `country_select` ?, it all depends on how you're building your form.

Comment: It's documentation page https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select
 `country_select("user", "country")`

Comment: but that's not a requirement, that's what they want to use, you can use it in many different ways, just look at what Alexander Luna posted, he gave you another example. That's why I say it really depends on how you're building your form.

Comment: I checked that out, but point is: if I understand correct I use form_for if I want to edit model, and I don't want to edit model in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In option 1 you are passing a collection `ISO3166::Country.countries.sort_by(&:name)` to `options_from_collection_for_select`. As you can see you have applied a sorting by name to the collection. It would be a matter of sorting your options as you want using `sort_by`.

```
PRIORITY_COUNTRIES = %w[RU BR IN CN ZA]

countries = ISO3166::Country.countries.sort_by do |country|
  priority_index = PRIORITY_COUNTRIES.index(country.alpha2)
  priority_index.present? ? priority_index.to_s : country.name
end
```

Note that I convert the index to string to be able to compare that to the country name.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by

Comment: Not quite sure how and where to implement this in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Am using rails 5.1.6 and this is the solution that worked for me.

Put the following in your Gemfile:

```
# country list
gem 'country_select'
```

On the command line, Install as a gem using:

```
gem install country_select
```

In your form view write:

```
<%= form.country_select :country, ([ "GB", "FR", "DE" ]), iso_codes: true, id: :element_id, class:"col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12" %>
```

In my model I added:

```
def country_name
 country = Country[country_code]
 country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [country_select](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) gem and use it in your form like this:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <%= f.country_select :country_code %>
<% end %>
```

If you don't want to use a gem, you can create a Ruby object that stores a list of all the countries with their abbreviation. Here is a ruby hash that you can use in your views:

https://github.com/karmi/localized_country_select/blob/master/locale/en.rb

Just copy it into your project and use it in your view.
I suggest you read Rails documentation about forms or else you might have problems in the future:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: I'm rather new to ruby, can you explain what is User.new in that instance?

So far my only run into form_for was using @articles:

    <%= form_for &#64;article do |f| %>

Comment: You can use @article too. It justs assumes that you wanted to create a user. But when you create an article you just replace User.new with your object (@article). I update my answer.

Comment: I'm kinda lost on the whole form_for: what do I need user for and what does it affect? (@article) stores data I don't want to affect with that form - I use it for searching/filtering.

Comment: In other words - I don't want to edit anything with that form, I'm using it purely to pass filtering parameters to my controller. Should I still use form_for in this case?

Comment: You are performing a search in your controller with the country code ?

Comment: Yes, basically controller looks like `@articles = Article.filter(params.slice(:category, :country, :src_url, :date, :lang, :keywords, :title)).where(is_active: true).paginate(:page => params[:page])` and model contains all those scopes (example: `scope :country, -> (country) { where country: country }`) right now. Although I will be remaking it for Sphinx in future. I had to branch country_select gem and edit it for myself to alter its output to 'name' instead of code.